# Php, catch redirect

Tags: php, redirect

so I have a code:

```
function testMe ($redir)
{
    if ($redir)
    {
        header ('Location: /');
    }
}
```

I want to test this function if it uses a redirection, but I dont know how to catch it. Its like catching an exception

EDIT: so I want if that `header()` wasnt written but know it was invoked

Comment: You mean you want to not redirect sometimes?  `header` should always work, could you be more clear with your question?

Comment: yea, I want to "nullify" the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//calling the function which somewhere does this
header('Location: /');

//testing
foreach (headers_list() as $header) {
    if (strpos($header, 'Location:') !== false) {
        //header location set, function works, removing the set header
        header_remove('Location');
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Now I just cant understand why does any code execute after the header() function...

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You haven't stopped it. If you were to put die() after the header() call then it wouldn't continue.